# how to attach file to list sharepoint 2013 via REST API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rest

I need to upload file as an attachement to list SharePoint using REST API.
UPload the file to list and not to SharedDocuments.
There is a COM code:
 http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-attach-files-to.html

but I need it in REST.
Best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example shows how to create a file attachment to a list item:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(item id)/AttachmentFiles/ add(FileName='file name')
method: POST
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    body: "Contents of file."
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-length:length of post body
```

**C# example**

```
 var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
 var endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{1}')/items({2})/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='{3}')",webUri,listTitle,itemId,fileName);


 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
 using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
 {
      var response =  client.PostAsync(endpointUrl, new StreamContent(stream)).Result;
 }
```

### References

[Working with files attached to list items by using REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553%28v=office.15%29.aspx#FileAttachments)

Comment: does this code works on SharePoint 2010?

Comment: @PranavBilurkar 6  years later, but anyway: no SP 2010 doesn't have the REST API. Only 2013+ does.

Answer (score 7):

```
$(document).ready( dofunc );

function dofunc() {
    var control = document.getElementById("ufile");
    control.addEventListener("change", fdocattach, false);
}

var file;
var contents;

function fdocattach(event) {
    var i = 0,
    files = event.srcElement.files,
    len = files.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        console.log("Filename: " + files[i].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes");
    }


    if (files.length > 0) {
        file = files[0];
        fileName = file.name;

        var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.onload = fonload;

        reader.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error("File reading error " + event.target.error.code);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }       
    return false;
}

function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new window.Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return binary;
}

function fonload(event) {
    contents = event.target.result;
    $.getScript("/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", fonload2);
}

function fonload2() {
    var contents2 = _arrayBufferToBase64(contents);

    var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor("/");
    createitem.executeAsync({
        url: "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List1')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
        method: "POST",
        binaryStringRequestBody: true,
        body: contents2,
        success: fsucc,
        error: ferr,
        state: "Update"
    });

    function fsucc(data) {
        alert('success');
    }

    function ferr(data) {
        alert('error\n\n' + data.statusText + "\n\n" + data.responseText);
    }
}
```

See this more information:
http://chuvash.eu/2013/02/20/rest-api-add-a-plain-text-file-as-an-attachment-to-a-list-item/

Comment: does this code works on SharePoint 2010?

Comment: This worked well for me. I had to add a `X-RequestDigest` header in the object that was passed to `createitem.executeAsync()`. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nadeemis/2012/10/23/tip-handling-http-403-forbidden-when-querying-the-search-rest-service-using-the-postquery-method/

Comment: This code helps me out to upload attachment to particular item, 

is there any way to create item through REST API along with multiple attachments in one call itself??

Answer (score 2):

Use the below one for getting the buffer. It uses deferred and promise

```
var getFileBuffer = function (file) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return deferred.promise();
};


function uploadattachment(id, listname) {
    if ($("#attachmentfile")[0].files.length > 0) {
        var file = $("#attachmentfile")[0].files[0];
        getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items(" + id + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                method: 'POST',
                data: buffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
                },
                success: function () {

                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```