# Upload multiple attachments

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

My requirements are for user to complete a bootstrap form, attach files, and on submit, create new list item and upload the attachments.

**CREATE NEW LIST ITEM**

Below code works on adding a new list item:

```
function addNewItem() {
var newSubject = $("#subject").val();
var newBody = $("#body").val();

var siteUrl = '/sites/XXXX';
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('FAQ2');

//Create new list item
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Title', newSubject);
    oListItem.set_item('Comments', newBody);
    oListItem.update();

clientContext.load(oListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        window.location.replace('/sites/XXXX/Pages/FAQ2.aspx');
    },
);
}
```

**ADDING ATTACHMENTS**
Source: [how to attach file to list sharepoint 2013 via REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122150/how-to-attach-file-to-list-sharepoint-2013-via-rest-api)

I inserted below lines above `window.location.replace('/sites/XXXX/Pages/FAQ2.aspx');`

```
itemId = oListItem.get_id();
uploadattachment(itemId);
```

And added below after `addNewItem()`

```
var getFileBuffer = function (file) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return deferred.promise();
};
function uploadattachment(itemId) {
    if ($("#getFile")[0].files.length > 0) {
        var count = $("#getFile")[0].files.length;
        for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {
            var file = $("#getFile")[0].files[i];
            alert(file.name);
            getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ2')/items(" + itemId + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: buffer,
                    processData: false,
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
                    },
                    success: function () {

                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The above code only uploads 1 attachment. I can't figure how to get it to add subsequent attachments. When i run the `alert(file.name);` it loops through the files being uploaded but only 1 is attached.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the below code for adding multiple attachments to a SharePoint list item :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oLoader;
var attcount = 0;
var arraycount = 0;
$(document).ready(function ($) {
$(‘#file_input’).multifile();//For facilitate multi file upload
$("#NewSaveItem").click(function () { formSave() });
});
function formSave() {
oLoader = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Working on it", "Creating New Bank Account…");
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
var data = [];
var fileArray = [];
$("#attachFilesHolder input:file").each(function () {
if ($(this)[0].files[0]) {
fileArray.push({ "Attachment": $(this)[0].files[0] });
}
});
data.push({
"Name": $("input[title=’Name’]").val(),
" Address ": $("input[title=’Address’]").val(),
"City": $("input[title= City]").val(),
"ContactNumber": $("input[title=’ContactNumber’]").val(),
"Files": fileArray
});
createNewItemWithAttachments("BankDetails", data).then(
function () {
if (oLoader.close) setTimeout(function () { oLoader.close(); window.location.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/BankDetails/AllItems.aspx"); }, 3000);
},
function (sender, args) {
console.log(‘Error occured’ + args.get_message());
}
)
}
}
var createNewItemWithAttachments = function (listName, listValues) {
var fileCountCheck = 0;
var fileNames;
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var dfd = $.Deferred();
var targetList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
context.load(targetList);
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var listItem = targetList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
listItem.set_item("Name", listValues[0].Name);
listItem.set_item("Address", listValues[0].Address);
listItem.set_item("City", listValues[0].City);
listItem.set_item("ContactNumber", listValues[0].ContactNumber);
listItem.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(
function () {
var id = listItem.get_id();
if (listValues[0].Files.length != 0) {
if (fileCountCheck <= listValues[0].Files.length – 1) {
loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck).then(
function () {
},
function (sender, args) {
console.log("Error uploading");
dfd.reject(sender, args);
}
);
}
}
else {
dfd.resolve(fileCountCheck);
}
},
function (sender, args) {
console.log(‘Error occured’ + args.get_message());
}
);
return dfd.promise();
}
function loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck) {
var dfd = $.Deferred();
uploadFileHolder(listName, id, listValues[0].Files[fileCountCheck].Attachment).then(
function (data) {
var objcontext = new SP.ClientContext();
var targetList = objcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
var listItem = targetList.getItemById(id);
objcontext.load(listItem);
objcontext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
console.log("Reload List Item- Success");
fileCountCheck++;
if (fileCountCheck <= listValues[0].Files.length – 1) {
loopFileUpload(listName, id, listValues, fileCountCheck);
} else {
console.log(fileCountCheck + ": Files uploaded");
attcount += fileCountCheck;
if (arraycount == attcount) {
if (oLoader.close) setTimeout(function () { oLoader.close(); window.location.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/BankDetails/AllItems.aspx"); }, 3000);
}
}
},
function (sender, args) {
console.log("Reload List Item- Fail" + args.get_message());
});
},
function (sender, args) {
console.log("Not uploaded");
dfd.reject(sender, args);
}
);
return dfd.promise();
}

function uploadFileHolder(listName, id, file) {
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var fileName = file.name;
getFileBuffer(file).then(
function (buffer) {
var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
var binary = ";
for (var b = 0; b < bytes.length; b++) {
binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[b]);
}
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
console.log(‘ File size:’ + bytes.length);
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () {
var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
createitem.executeAsync({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘" + listName + "‘)/items(" + id + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName=’" + file.name + "‘)",
method: "POST",
binaryStringRequestBody: true,
body: binary,
success: fsucc,
error: ferr,
state: "Update"
});

function fsucc(data) {
console.log(data + ‘ uploaded successfully’);
deferred.resolve(data);
}

function ferr(data) {
console.log(fileName + "not uploaded error");
deferred.reject(data);
}
});
},
function (err) {
deferred.reject(err);
}
);
return deferred.promise();
}

function getFileBuffer(file) {
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
}
reader.onerror = function (e) {
deferred.reject(e.target.error);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
return deferred.promise();
}
</script>
```

Reference URL :

[Upload multiple attachments to list items using JSOM and REST API in SharePoint Online/2013/2016](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/upload-multiple-attachments-to-list-items-using-jsom-and-rest-api-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: i'm getting `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` in `loopFileUpload`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and you need to make sure that the first file is uploaded successfully before trying to upload the next file. Note that I used 3 file input, accepting a single file for each control.

```
function uploadAttachments(ID, listName, fileControl) {

    var fileDeffered = $.Deferred();

    var fileInput = $("#" + fileControl);

    if(fileInput.get(0).files.length !== 0) {

        var file = fileInput.get(0).files[0];

        var getFileBuffer = function(file) {    
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
                }
                reader.onerror = function(e) {
                    deferred.reject(e.target.error);
                }
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            return deferred.promise();
        };

        getFileBuffer(file).then(function(buffer) {
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + ID + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
                method: 'POST',
                data: buffer,
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    fileDeffered.resolve();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    fileDeffered.reject();
                    errorMsg(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    return fileDeffered.promise();
};
```

Called the above function when the actual list item were successfully created.

```
success: function (data) {

    var newItemID = data.d.ID;

    if($("input:file").get(0).files.length !== 0) {

        $.when(
            uploadAttachments(newItemID, listName, 'file1').then(function() {
                uploadAttachments(newItemID, listName, 'file2').then(function() {
                    uploadAttachments(newItemID, listName, 'file3').then(function() {
                    })
                })
            })
        ).done(function() {
            successMsg();
        });
    }
    else {
        successMsg();
    }
};
```

I'm sure there's better ways to solve this but this is how I did it.

Comment: Thanks but I rather have only 1 input control that accepts multiple files but this is worth looking into if I can't figure out the former

Comment: Ah, some slight modifications should be enough, went with multiple options as my users needed to select files from different folders. :)